# Angular js directives apply changes to all instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to create a directive for sorting if i dont sort any other column it is looking good but when i select another column previous icon is not resetting to default.

Default screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP4V5.png)

After sorting different columns
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcduu.png)

Directive Instance

```
<sort-th data-options="self.query" 
sort-prop="name"
col-name="Name"
sort-callback="self.sort('name')" />
```

inside directive

```
var template = function(){        
   return '<div> <span>{{colName}} </span><span class="fa fa-sort{{sortIcon}}">      </span> </div>';
};

function sortIcon(options, prop){
if(options.sort !== prop){
return '';
} else if(options.sort === prop && options.order === 1){
return "-desc";
} else if(options.sort === prop && options.order === -1){
return "-asc";
}        
}
return {
scope: {
sortOptions: '=options',
sortProp: '@',
colName: '@',
callback: '&sortCallback'
},
replace: 'true',
restrict: 'AE',    
template: template,
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
scope.sortIcon = sortIcon(scope.sortOptions, scope.sortProp);

elem.on("click", function() {                
scope.sortOptions.sort = scope.sortProp;
scope.sortOptions.order = (scope.sortOptions.order === 1)? -1 : 1;
scope.sortIcon = sortIcon(scope.sortOptions, scope.sortProp);
scope.callback();
});
}
};
}]);
```

Comment: Problem solved, I replaced my template function with

    return '<div> <span>{{colName}} </span><span class="fa" data-ng-class="{\'fa-sort-desc\': (sortOptions.sort == sortProp && sortOptions.order == 1),\'fa-sort-asc\': (sortOptions.sort == sortProp && sortOptions.order == -1),\'fa-sort\':(sortOptions.sort != sortProp)}"></span> </div>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I replaced my template function with

return ' {{colName}}  ';